# Механизм логирования действий в проекте

Tags: c++, логирование, макросы, стек

Собираюсь написать свое логирование действий в проекте. В частности, чтобы отслеживать стек вызовов функций до возникновения необрабатываемого исключения.

1. Какая информация является необходимой и достаточной для этого? Достаточно ли для этого механизма вызывать логировщик при входе в тело ключевой функции, выходе из него и в обработчике исключений? Или нужно еще когда-то?

Я предполагаю сохранять в файле лога время вызова инструкции логирования, имя файла исходного кода, номер строчки файла исходного кода, имя функции. И еще сообщение - либо что действие осуществлено (успешно), либо что сгенерировано исключение; с какой-то дополнительной информацией, например, аргументами функции.

2. Не уверен насчет полезности времени, нашел макрос `__TIME__`, но там точность до секунд. Есть ли макрос, обеспечивающий время с большей точностью? Или использовать системное время `time()`?
3. Имя файла выдает макрос `__FILE__`, а номер строчки `__LINE__`, верно? Других способов, кроме как через эти макросы, получить такую информацию нет?
4. Как узнать имя функции, в которй вызвана инструкция логирования? Если эта функция - метод класса, то будет ли название полным и со всеми спецификаторами?

Используется MS Visual Studio 2015, компилятор VC++.

P.S. Вопрос к экспертам boost. В проекте используется этот фреймворк, в частности, библиотека boost.log. Пока не встретил никаких трудностей с ней, но может есть какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: Макросы `__DATE__` и `__TIME__` дают дату и время **компиляции программы**. Имя функции дает макрос `__func__`, но тут у каждого компилятора свои варианты вывода, как и дополнительные свои макросы, помимо данного.

Comment: мне очень помогает severity level. Есть куча логов. У каждого лога может быть выставлено данное свойство. Допустим severity_debug, severity_warning, severity_notify. Если из внешней программы посылаю команду severity_debug то в лог файл начинают сыпаться абсолютно все логи. Иначе  - выборочно.
Имя функции не обязательно, есть номер строки - этого достаточно .

Comment: @YuryMelnikov, а почему имя функции необязательно? Я планирую этот механизм использовать частично и в релизе, например, если пользователь «испортит» некоторый файл со входными данными, который парсится в функции, то в логировщике будет указано сообщение, какая именно функция валится, чтобы можно было найти ее в документации и понять, где именно используется этот файл и кем. А вот информация о расположении в исходном коде тут будет бесполезна.